# How do I make my character jumps in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, 2d-games

I'm new to Phaser 3, and I'm trying to make my character jump.

Here is my code:

```js
create() {
    this.kid = this.physics.add.sprite(50, 380, 'idle');
    this.kid.setScale(.3);
    this.kid.setGravityY(300);
    this.kid.setBounce(0.2);
    this.kid.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
    this.physics.add.collider(this.kid, this.platforms);
    this.cursorKeys = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys()
}

update() {
    this.moveKid()
}

moveKid() {
    if (this.cursorKeys.left.isDown) {
        this.kid.setVelocityX(-300)
    } else if (this.cursorKeys.right.isDown) {
        this.kid.setVelocityX(300)
    } else {
        this.kid.setVelocityX(0);
        this.kid.setVelocityY(0);
    }
    if (this.cursorKeys.up.isDown && this.kid.body.touching.down) {
        this.kid.setVelocityY(-300);
    }
}
```

But currently, the character only jumps a few pixels up and thats all. If I remove the `touching.down` part, the player jumps freely but also jumps in the air and falls very, very slow (no matter the gravity I set to it to).

Could anyone help?

Comment: Check out one of the official tutorials [here](http://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-3-game). This goes through the basics of implementing player and object physics, with key movement.

Answer (score 3):

You would want to remove the line in your code where you set the character's y velocity to zero whenever there's no keyboard input. It stops the character's motion every time the game updates, hence the slow fall speed.